# DownloadFile in ASP mvc 4 from physical path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp-classic, download

I need to make downloading files from the server . Server is specified physical path.
the file is downloaded , but there are problems that I do not know how to fix .
1) All the files are named as "Download".2) does not have an extension . Help me, please, I'm new to ASP MVC

Code of Controller :

```
        public ActionResult NIRInfo()
    {
        List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
        var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"Z:\Docs");
        System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
        var xow = from i in db.NIRs where i.Id == id select i.File;
        foreach (var i in xow)
        {
            fileNames = dir.GetFiles(i);
            foreach (var f in fileNames)
            {
                filesList.Add(f.Name);
            }
            ViewData["fList"] = filesList;
        }
        return View(nir);

    }

    public FileResult Download(string Name)
    {
        return File(@"Z:\Docs\" + Name,  MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    }
```

Code of view

```
                            @{ var fList = ViewData["fList"] as List<string>;}

                        @if (ViewData["fList"] != null)
                        {
                            <table>
                                @foreach (var f in fList)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="@Url.Action("Download", "NIR", new {  Name = @f })">@f</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </table>
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a filename in method overload. Look at **third** parameter in `File` method

```
public FileResult Download(string Name)
{
    return File(@"Z:\Docs\" + Name,  MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "document.txt");
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i need to download files with any extensions, Can you help me?

Comment: ouh thanks, i just locate Name in third parameters. very greate.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpResponseBase response;

response.Clear();
response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
response.TransmitFile(Path.Combine(FileName, Path.GetFileName(fileName )));
```

Comment: thx for answer, but where i can locate this code?? in the actionresult NIRInfo()?

Comment: Basically what I do is create a new action filter that extends FilePathResult, and there initialize the base path and content type. And from controller method I just call the FilterName with passing the filePath, FileName and type. Also while we access the shared location rather than giving rights to everyone, make a account and just give access right to it. And use that account as iis app pool identity. Hope this helps